# Write a function called findHypot

Tags: python

My assignment: Write a function called `findhypot`. The function will be given the length of two sides of a right-angled triangle and it should return the length of the hypotenuse

I came up with the following solution:

```
def findhypot(a , b):
    ((a*a)+(b*b)%2)
    return a , b

a = int(input("Pls lenter length of Opposite: "))
b = int(input("Pls enter the length of Adjascent: "))

print("The lenght of the hypotenous is",findhypot)
```

But instead of the correct value I get the following output:

```
The lenght of the hypotenous is <function findhypot at 0xgibberish>
```

Comment: You're going to need to specify what you're asking. Note though that `((a*a)+(b*b)%2)` doesn't do anything because you don't store the result from it anywhere, I don't think you want modulo (`%`) there, and you never call the function.

Comment: Also, you're printing out a reference to the function findhypot, not calling it and printing the return value. It should be `findhypot(a,b)` instead.

Comment: @teukkam That comment is probably the basis for an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code, but let's look at the output first. You get that output, because you are not calling the function that you defined:

```
print("The lenght of the hypotenous is",findhypot)
```

So instead of just putting `findhypot` in your `print` you should call it and pass the two paramters that you just received via `input`:

```
print("The lenght of the hypotenous is",findhypot(a,b))
```

But that will give you (assuming your input is 3 and 4):

```
The lenght of the hypotenous is (3, 4)
```

Why that? Because you are just returning a and b in your function without any further calculation:

```
return a , b
```

Without further calculation? But there is a line doing something with a,b! Yes, but that calculated value is never assigned or returned, so either use a variable to get the result of the calculation:

```
def findhypot(a , b):
    result = ((a*a)+(b*b)%2)
    return result
```

Or return the calculation directly:

```
def findhypot(a , b):
    return ((a*a)+(b*b)%2)
```

But now you will get 9 as result for 3 and 4. 5 should be the correct value. I leave it up to you to find the soluton for that problem. Hint: Pythagoras, `import math` and `math.sqrt(...)`

Comment: Awesome...  I understand now

Comment: Awesome...  I understand now